# Ember js build throws null coalescing error

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I'm following the guide [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/patterns-for-components/#toc_argument-defaults) to create getters in my component. However following the guide as it is gives me an error

> Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't
>   currently enabled

Searching through the guides, I couldn't find any documentation on how to enable this. I've tried this in my `ember-cli-build.js` file but that didn't work

```
'ember-cli-babel': {
  includePolyfill: true,
  nullishCoalescingOperator: true
}
```

and

```
'ember-cli-babel': {
  includePolyfill: true,
  nullishCoalescingOperator: 'enabled'
}
```

**Update** This works by manually installing the plug-in like the accepted answer shows, however even after upgrading `ember-cli-babel` to the latest version, it didn't work by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a plugin to the ember-cli build you should follow [this format](https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel#usage). For the nullish coalescing operator you would also need to `npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator`.

However as of [January 10th 2020](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/10811) the easiest way to get nullish coalescing is to ensure you have the latest version of `ember-cli-babel` `v7.13.2` which contains the newest `@babel/preset-env` `v7.8.3` which includes this plugin by default and then you won't need to make any changes to your build.

You can see what version of `@babel/preset-env` you are running with the command `npm ls @babel/preset-env`. If it is before `v7.8.3` then you might need to update it, I usually do this by updating all the transitive dependencies with:

```sh
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was on `7.13.0` already but tried `7.13.2` and it still doesn't work.

Got it to work by manually installing the plugin like you showed.

Comment: Glad I included both! I added some details on updating these second level dependencies which might work for you and prevent you needed to keep that package up to date.